# combobox no funciona al seleccionar celda de datagridview por primera vez

Tags: c#, datagridview

tengo un datagridview que cargo en forma manual, y varios combobox y texbox aparte en el form, que al seleccionar cualquier celda del datagrid se actualizan los textbox y combobox del form.

mi problema es que cuando selecciono por primera vez la celda no funcionan los cobobox (no aparece nada), en los textbox si, al cambiar de row (otra celda de otra fila) si aparece y ya funciona normal, inclusive volver a seleccionar el anterior que no aparecía... este es el código:

```
private void Grid1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

Combo1.SelectedValue=Convert.ToInt16(Grid1.Rows[Grid1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[7].Value);
   Combo2.SelectedValue=Convert.ToInt16(Grid1.Rows[Grid1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[8].Value);

   Fecha.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(Grid1.Rows[Grid1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[1].Value);

   Txt1.Text = Grid1.Rows[Grid1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

}
```

Agradeceria la orientacion que me puedan brindar

Comment: ¿Y has verifiado que los `items` de los `combos` contienen el valor que intentas establecer como  `SelectedValue`? Ten en cuenta que si un valor determinado no ha sido previamente agregado a la colección  `Items` del Combo, al intentar establecerlo como `SelectedValue`, no se podrá mostrar, por que sencillamente ese valor no está entre los valores posibles a seleccionar.

Comment: eso es lo extraño, que al ver el debug, tiene el valor correcto, pero no se muestran, Por ejemplo al abrir el form, muestra los renglones del grid, y seleccionas cualquier celda, y solo salen los texbox, pero los combobox no, inmediatamente seleccionas otra celda en otra fila (otra celda de la misma fila no funciona) y si los muestras.

Comment: Bueno lo otro que queda por revisar es que los `items` agregados a los `combos`, se hayan agregado como `Int16`, es decir que coincidan los tipos entre los objetos almacenados en la colección `Items` del `Combo` con el tipo del valor que se pretende establecer como `SelectedValue`. Seria util que icluyeras el codigo en donde se llenan la colección `Items` de los `Combos`.

Comment: gracias amigo eduardo reyes, pero si ese fuera el problema, al darle click en otro row tampoco funcionaria

Comment: lo solucione, antes de asignar el selectedvalue le asigno un text que exista en los valores del combo... es decir Combo1.Text="valor1"; Combo1.SelectedValue=Convert.ToInt16(Grid1.Rows[Grid1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[7].Value); luego si le coloca el text que corresponde al selectedvalue.... todavia no entiendo que pasa pero funciona.